# Apple ID IOS 11 beta feature, NFC option is greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode

I am experimenting with the new IOS 11 (still in beta) NFC feature but I cannot enable the option on the web site:

When editing the bundle ID, to enable the option I cannot select the
NFC tick box, it is greyed out.

- This is an enterprise account, I am not sure if this has anything to
  to with this.
- The bundle identifier is a wildcard.

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle/edit

Comment: Have you tried on a non-wildcard bundle identifier?

Comment: you are correct :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a different bundle id, one that is not a wildcard you are
able to select the NFC option, to enable it.